# Add new option to LoadDataFixture command

Tags: symfony

I'd like to add a new option to my `doctrine:fixtures:load` console command.

```
class LoadDataFixturesCommand extends LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function configure() 
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this->addOption('custom', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Your Custom Option');
    }
}
```

When I run my command like this:

> doctrine:fixtures:load --custom

I got this error message:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
>     The "--custom" option does not exist.

How can I add this option to my console command?

Comment: Did you add `use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;` and `use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;` in your `LoadDataFixturesCommand ` class?

Comment: Yep, added all. There is not like this. Declarations are fine, and the fixtures  class loaded already. The message come right after.

Comment: I think this question could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596218/how-to-get-command-argument-outside-command-class

Comment: That was my first try. The problem is, it won't get until execute(). I've tried again now, but it's not working. Look like the option assigned to the object ($this) when dumped, it contains my "custom" option but throw exception anyway.

Comment: Notice. It seems that it works on Symfony 2.x but not in symfony 3.x

Answer (score 0):

you can rename the function:

```
protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this->setName('app:fixtures:load')
           ->addOption('custom-option', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Your Custom Option');
    }
```

on this way the command

```
php app/console app:fixtures:load
```

will call you personal execute function.